# '?' appears when using std::wcout to output wchar_t data type

Tags: c++, unicode, wchar-t

I was trying to output some characters using `std::wcout`, but it sent `?` to the output instead of the intended characters. Running ubuntu Linux 20.04.

code:

```
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    wchar_t z {L'\x00E7'};
    wchar_t lz {L'z'};

    std::wcout << z << std::endl << lz;
}
```

output:

```
?
z
```

The hexadecimal number assigned to `z` corresponds to c-cedilla (`Ç`).

Can someone help me understand why this occurred? No error messages were thrown.

Comment: what terminal program?

Comment: What encoding does your terminal use?

Comment: I thought `\x` only took 2 following hex characters, you'd need `\u` to use all 4.

Comment: @MarkRansom https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape: "*Hexadecimal escape sequences have no length limit and terminate at the first character that is not a valid hexadecimal digit. If the value represented by a single hexadecimal escape sequence does not fit the range of values represented by the character type used in this string literal (char, char8_t (since C++20), char16_t, char32_t (since C++11), or wchar_t), the result is unspecified.*" So `L'\x00E7'` is a 2 byte value that is valid for a `wchar_t` since it is at least 2 bytes in size.

Comment: @DanielA.White I ran the code via codeblocks on ubuntu linux. Not entirely sure if that answers your question lol.

Comment: @Brian i'm not sure and don't know how to check that to be honest. Would that be unicode vs ascii or utf-8 vs utf-16 type of thing?

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right, I must have been thinking of a different language then.  I can see how that feature might lead to some hard to find bugs though.  Thanks!